# Parsing LLVM IR code (with debug symbols) to map it back to the original source

Tags: parsing, abstract-syntax-tree, debug-symbols, llvm-ir

I'm thinking about building a tool to help me visualise the generated LLVM-IR code for each instruction/function on my original source file.
Something like [this](https://rust.godbolt.org/) but for LLVM-IR.

The steps to build such tool so far seem to be:

- Start by with LLVM-IR AST builder.
- Parse generated IR code.
- On caret position get AST element.
- Read the element scope, line, column and
  file and signal it on the original source file.

Is this the correct way to approach it? Am I trivialising it too much?

Comment: Looks quite correct. The thing you want to achieve is rather simple with llvm, but will require a lot of UI code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your approach is quite correct. The UI part will probably be quite long to implement so I'll focus on the llvm part.

Let's say you start from a input file containing your LLVM-IR.

**Step 1** process module:
Read file content to a string. Then Build a module from it, and process it to get the debug info:

```
llvm::MemoryBuffer* buf = llvm::MemoryBuffer::getMemBuffer(llvm::StringRef(fileContent)).release();
llvm::SMDiagnostic diag;
llvm::Module* module = llvm::parseIR(buf->getMemBufferRef(), diag, *context).release();
llvm::DebugInfoFinder* dif = new llvm::DebugInfoFinder();
dif->processModule(*module);
```

**Step 2** iterate on instructions:
Once done with that, you can simply iterate on function and blocks and instructions:

```
// pseudo code for loops (real code is a bit long)
foreach(llvm::Function f in module.functions) 
{
   foreach(llvm::BasicBlock b in f.BasicBlockList)
   {
      foreach(llvm::Instruction inst in b.InstList) 
      {
         llvm::DebugLoc dl = inst.getDebugLoc();
         unsigned line = dl->getLine();
         // accordingly populate some dictionary between your instructions and source code
      }
   }
}
```

**Step 3** update your UI
This is another story...

Comment: What is the *context supposed to be? I found examples where getGlobalContext() is used but I don't have it defined on my "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h".

Comment: it is just a new context, of type llvm::LLVMContext

Comment: As @Regis Portalez said the for code is a bit longer. To iterate over each collection I figure out to do it like this: for (auto curFref = m->getFunctionList().begin(),
         endFref = module->getFunctionList().end();
         curFref != endFref; ++curFref) {...}

Comment: How do I know where the llvm::Instruction is on the LLVM-IR source?